# showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{d9d3093 VFE...... .F....ID 0,0-1440,2956 #1 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INP

Tags: flutter, dart, android-emulator

after trying to input text in textfromfield emulator keyboard dosen't shows up also not taking any text. using flutter version - 3.10

tried updataing permission but didn't work

code

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
const LoginScreen({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var controller = Get.put(AuthController());

```
return bgWidget(
    child: Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  body: Center(
    child: Column(children: [
      (context.screenHeight * 0.1).heightBox,
      applogoWidget(),
      10.heightBox,
      "Welcome to $appname".text.white.fontFamily(bold).size(18).make(),
      15.heightBox,
      Obx(
        () => Column(
          children: [
            customTextfield(
                title: email,
                hint: emailHint,
                isPass: false,
                controller: controller.emailController),
            customTextfield(
                title: password,
                hint: passwordHint,
                isPass: true,
                controller: controller.passwordController),
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: forgetPassword.text.make(),
                )),
            5.heightBox,
            controller.isLoading.value
                ? const CircularProgressIndicator(
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(redColor),
                  )
                : logInButton(
                    title: logIn,
                    color: redColor,
                    textColor: whiteColor,
                    onPressed: () async {
                      controller.isLoading(true);
                      await controller
                          .logInMethod(context: context)
                          .then((value) {
                        if (value != null) {
                          VxToast.show(context, msg: "Logged in");
                          Get.offAll(() => const Home());
                        } else {
                          controller.isLoading(false);
                        }
                      });
                    }).box.width(context.screenWidth - 50).make(),
            5.heightBox,
            createAccount.text.color(fontGrey).make(),
            5.heightBox,
            logInButton(
                title: signUp,
                color: golden,
                textColor: whiteColor,
                onPressed: () {
                  Get.to(() => const SignUpScreen());
                }).box.width(context.screenWidth - 50).make(),
            10.heightBox,
            logInWith.text.color(fontGrey).make(),
            5.heightBox,
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: List<Widget>.generate(
                  3,
                  (index) => Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: lightGrey,
                          radius: 25,
                          child: Image.asset(
                            socailIconList[index],
                            width: 30,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )),
            ),
          ],
        )
            .box
            .white
            .rounded
            .padding(const EdgeInsets.all(18))
            .width(context.width - 70)
            .shadowSm
            .make(),
      ),
    ]),
  ),
));
```

}
}